# Python statsmodels OLS: how to save learned model to file

Tags: python, least-squares, statsmodels

I am trying to learn an ordinary least squares model using Python's statsmodels library, as described [here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS).

sm.OLS.fit() returns the learned model. Is there a way to save it to the file and reload it? My training data is huge and it takes around half a minute to learn the model. So I was wondering if any save/load capability exists in OLS model.

I tried the `repr()` method on the model object but it does not return any useful information.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The models and results instances all have a save and load method, so you don't need to use the pickle module directly.

**Edit** to add an example:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

data = sm.datasets.longley.load_pandas()

data.exog['constant'] = 1

results = sm.OLS(data.endog, data.exog).fit()
results.save("longley_results.pickle")

# we should probably add a generic load to the main namespace
from statsmodels.regression.linear_model import OLSResults
new_results = OLSResults.load("longley_results.pickle")

# or more generally
from statsmodels.iolib.smpickle import load_pickle
new_results = load_pickle("longley_results.pickle")
```

**Edit 2** We've now added a `load` method to main statsmodels API in master, so you can just do

```
new_results = sm.load('longley_results.pickle')
```

Comment: Additionally, if you use the pickled results and model only for prediction, then it is possible to strip the training data (but many methods won't work anymore) statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.save.html

Comment: @jseabold could you give an example?

Comment: Sure. Edited to add an example.

Comment: jseabold: I tried the `sm.load` method but the interpreter complains that the module does not have 'load' attribute. Is there a new version of statsmodels that I should be using?

Comment: It is in master on github and will be in the next release. You need to install from source if you want to use it now.

Comment: any alternative strategy to save in a json file for example?

Comment: You can use the json module (or pandasjson) just as you would the pickle module to dump results objects to json. We have plans to make something built-in for the next release.

Answer (score 8):

I've installed the statsmodels library and found that you can save the values using the [pickle module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) in python.

> Models and results are pickleable via save/load, optionally saving the model data.
>   [[source]](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statsmodels)

As an example:

Given that you have the results saved in the variable results:

To save the file:

```
import pickle    
with open('learned_model.pkl','w') as f:
  pickle.dump(results,f)
```

To read the file:

```
import pickle
with open('learned_model.pkl','r') as f:
  model_results = pickle.load(f)
```