# Calculate values w/ statsmodels given a formula and parameters

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

I have fitted a model given a Poly-3 function and extracted the found parameters

```
model = smf.ols(formula='A ~ B + I(B ** 2.0) + I(B ** 3.0)', data=sp)
poly_3 = model.fit()
params = poly_3.params.values
```

I want to save the params for later use since I don't want to train the model each time. Params would e.g. be `[ 0.09525563,  0.09655527, -0.00946222,  0.00056942]`

**How can I then, given the formula, the params and some x-values get fitted values?**
I am thinking of sth. like this:

```
OLS.predict(x=range(20), params=params, formula='A ~ B + I(B ** 2.0) + I(B ** 3.0)')
```

I obviously could write the formula in Python itself, but I feel that I don't have to re-invent the wheel here!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this [Python statsmodels OLS: how to save learned model to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420407/python-statsmodels-ols-how-to-save-learned-model-to-file) 
you can save your model results to a pickle file, then load the model from the pickle file and use it to predict.

Let me know if you have any questions.