# Exporting statistical model in Python

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

Is it possible in Python to export statistical model from statsmodel library to file and then import that model to other program?

Comment: What kind of other other programs? What information? E.g. the estimated coefficients can be written to any text file and the results can be pickled. The full model is implemented in python and there are no tools to write them in some cross-package "model definition format".

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Python statsmodels OLS: how to save learned model to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420407/python-statsmodels-ols-how-to-save-learned-model-to-file)

Comment: @Jarad, thanks, It helped me